# Error when trying to move directory from sites-available to sites-enabled nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, nginx

I followed this tutorial on how to setup Django, Gunicorn and Nginx on Digital Ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-and-configure-a-new-django-project

At one point, the tutorial told me to run the: `sudo nginx -t` command to check for errors. I ran it and it gave me this output:

```
tudor@Pia-Droplet:~$ sudo nginx -t
[sudo] password for tudor:
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/PiaBlog" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
```

The i ran another command to make sure that my website dir was moved from sites available to sites enabled:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/PiaBlog /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

the output is :

```
tudor@Pia-Droplet:~$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/PiaBlog /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/PiaBlog': File exists
```

Could you help me and find out why this error occurs.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ln -s` does not move the directory, it creates a "symbolic link" (basically: a note that this directory is really stored elsewhere). It seems like the symbolic link already exists, so you will need to delete the old one (you can delete it just like a regular file), before you can create a new (correct) one.